# Parse Server - Missing Push Configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, parse-server, bitnami

I've been trying to get push notifications to work with my Parse application. I tried to do so my adding the below code into my Parse server.js file but my server does not start up again when this code is contained inside of the file. I have my p12 file available and linked in the code below (on my actual sever) as well so Im not sure what the issue is.

```
push: {
    android: {
      senderId: '...',
      apiKey: '...'
      },
    ios: {
      pfx: '/file/path/to/XXX.p12',
      passphrase: '', // optional password to your p12/PFX
      bundleId: '',
      production: false
    } 
 }
```

My server is running on an Amazon EC2 instance as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using AWS SNS to use push notification? If so, you can try setting this in your server code:

```
function sendPhoneNotification() {
    AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: '***',
        secretAccessKey: '***',
        region: 'ap-southeast-1'
    });

    var sns = new AWS.SNS();
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();
    sns.createPlatformEndpoint({
        PlatformApplicationArn: '***',
        Token: "***"
    }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        console.log("Error in endpoint" + err.stack);
        //res.error("error stack 1: " + err.stack);
        promise.reject(err.stack);
        return promise;
        }
        var endpointArn = data.EndpointArn;
        var payload = {
        GCM: {
        data: {
        title: "YOUR TITLE",
        message: "HELLO PUSH NOTIFICATION"
        }
        }
        /*  APNS: {
            aps: {
            alert: 'Hello World',
            sound: 'default',
            badge: 1
            }
        }*/
        };
        // payload.APNS = JSON.stringify(payload.APNS);
        payload.GCM = JSON.stringify(payload.GCM);
        payload = JSON.stringify(payload);
        var result = sns.publish({
        Message: payload,
        MessageStructure: 'json',
        TargetArn: endpointArn
        }, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            promise.reject(err.stack);
            return promise;
        }
        res.success("push sent " + JSON.stringify(data));

    });

});
return promise;
```

}